# External HDD can't be detected on My Computer

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Disc Management SC - can't find my external HDD:

[image: Disc Management SC - can't find my external HDD]

My Computer SC -  can't access my external HDD:

[image: My Computer SC - can't access my external HDD]

Attached above are the screenshots showing how i can't access the files i have on my external HDD. It was still working perfectly fine yesterday but i was unable to access it today. What should i do to atleast fix the external HDD or recover the file?

Thanks

Comment: unplugged your external hard disk directly?

Comment: @vembutech i think before this happened i shut down the laptop before removing the external HDD

Comment: try testdisk/photorec from cgsecurity